# Who creates user default_user?

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cli, localstack

I'm learning about users in the context of AWS.

I've freshly installed `LocalStack`, `AWS CLI` and run `aws configure` - *and that's all*.

But it looks like there's automatically a user named `default_user` created:

```
$ aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4593 iam get-user
{
    "User": {
        "Path": "/",
        "UserName": "default_user",
        "UserId": "ne4s0hfrh6t9bizsnyxd",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/default_user",
        "CreateDate": "2020-04-28T22:19:20.834000+00:00"
    }
}
```

**Who created the user `default_user` and why?**

How does this relate to real, live AWS? I imagine that real AWS doesn't just create users without some explicit action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config` files (`%UserProfile%\.aws\credentials` on Windows). These are created by running `aws config`.

access_key_id/secret belongs to AWS IAM user, which in your case is a "default user". So someone in IAM created this user and you entered access key of that user in `aws configure`.

Comment: "access_key_id/secret belongs to AWS IAM user"; my next confusion: does the access_key_id/secret *identify* a user? My confusion is this: when your run a service operation like "s3 mb", I know that under-the-hood, the credentials are used to certify the operation, but do those credentials also identify the user? I guess I don't understand how a command like "s3 mb" *could not* be associated with a user, so I'm trying to understand how the user is identified when you run something like "s3 mb" etc.

Comment: Not really... Key and Secret are basically just random sequences of characters. Your CLI program must reach out to AWS services to retrieve/confirm the identity of the user.

Comment: if/when you happen to be free, please drop by this chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212813/about-aws-users-and-credentials - hopefully I can explain my confusion better over there vs. the limited space of this comment section.

Comment: BTW - if you are looking for the "local S3" emulation, besides localstack - take a look at https://min.io/